# How to get a lodash custom (reduced) build suitable for es modules import?

Tags: javascript, lodash, es6-modules

I mean for example:

```
lodash include=each,find,filter,map,some,debounce,defer,delay,throttle,uniq,assign,extend,merge,omit,without,findIndex,compact,replace,groupBy,max,uniqueId
```

When I try to import in es modules, I get a warning like this:

*Bundled and transpiled successfully, but with warnings: The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten*

Is there any option to have the same custom (reduced) build, but suitable to be imported in modules and then available through `'_'` as always?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own [aggregating module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) in a local file...such as `tools/lodash.js`:

```
export { 
  each, find, filter, map, some, debounce, defer, delay, throttle,
  uniq, assign, extend, merge, omit, without, findIndex, compact, 
  replace, groupBy, max, uniqueId 
} from 'lodash';
```

Then when you wanted these tools you could add

```
import * as _ from './tools/lodash`;
```

If you don't like the `import * as _` syntax, you could do a straight import in your aggregating module and then do an `export default { each, find, ... };`. That would allow you to do `import _ from './tools/lodash';`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! In fact, since I use lodash along with other libraries in severa pages (shared libraries), after importing like `import * as _ from './tools/lodash` I'm adding it to the global scope like `window._ = _; ` so that it will be available to other module js files added in page after the shared.js file. This also allows  me avoiding bundling the same script/functions in several page-specific modules.